# python getting Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder

Tags: python

I am trying to use selenium in python and I am getting the following error: 
Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from selenium import selenium
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 25, in <module>
    import httplib as http_client
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
>>>
```

OSX 10.11.1
python 2.7.10

I can't figure out if this is an El Capitan issue, python issue. Tried brew doctor and system is ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out it was a python issue, after installing a new version of python. Running this solved the issue:

```
hash -r python
```

Comment: I have the same issue, with python twilio library. Can you explain more about how you solve it? I got 'too many arguments' complain running hash -r python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most probably caused by **Brew Installed** python.

The python official website provides downloads for macOS, you should download and install the official package.

The official installer will fix the python link automatic, then issue solved.