# Python 2.7: Import Error for 'matplotlib' and 'plotly' (OS X)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, plotly

I am trying to import **matplotlib** and **plotly** in my python script to plot a simple distribution. Earlier when I was running the script, it was displaying nothing on the command-line and it seemed that it was simply processing the `import` statement.

To debug it, I upgraded python using `brew install python` after that and did a `pip install --upgrade pip` after that. Using the upgraded **pip**, I made sure that **matplotlib** and **plotly** are installed. But, upon running the script, I am getting the following error on command-line:

```
$ python script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install the latest versions of matplotlib and plotly after upgrading Python? What version of Python were you previously on?

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE, yes. I confirmed the same after installation by trying `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` and `pip install --upgrade plotly`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar SO issue for Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390291/2821252). The problem appeared to be a python issue after updating and the solution there was to type `hash -r python` in the terminal. Worth a try.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out